# How to install postgresql-9.4 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

Tried `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4` but it doesn't find it.

How can I install this version?

Comment: Does it really have to be 9.4 or would 9.5 suffice ?

Comment: I need it to reflect the AWS version which is 9.4. :(  At least I need the client of 9.4 to talk to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`, and add a line for the repository:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main
```

Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.4 postgresql-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4 libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.4

# pgAdmin III graphical administration utility
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 just replace `xenial` with `bionic`.